# Return the maximum of all groups?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider a simple table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE example_groups(
                            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                            value1 INT NOT NULL,
                            value2 INT NOT NULL,
                            user_name TEXT NOT NULL
                          );
```

With some rows in it:

```
INSERT INTO example_groups(value1, value2, user_name) VALUES(3, 1, 'Tom');
INSERT INTO example_groups(value1, value2, user_name) VALUES(5, 2, 'Tom');
INSERT INTO example_groups(value1, value2, user_name) VALUES(1, 3, 'Tom');
INSERT INTO example_groups(value1, value2, user_name) VALUES(40, 10, 'John');
INSERT INTO example_groups(value1, value2, user_name) VALUES(1, 11, 'John');
```

I have the following query to group by the table by the `user_name` column:

```
SELECT SUM(value1), SUM(value2),  MAX(value2)
FROM example_groups
GROUP BY user_name;
```

What the result returns I am going to insert it into another table (the query is `INSERT SELECT`).

I want to return to my code the maximal value of all the rows in the `MAX` column. So far I have been doing this with the `RETURNING` statement, however when I try to use it here I get an error.

What is the correct way to use the `RETURNING` statement in this scenario ?

Example of a failing query:

```
SELECT SUM(value1), SUM(value2), MAX(value2) AS max2
FROM example_groups
RETURNING (MAX(max2))
GROUP BY user_name;
```

Ps I am using postgres.

Comment: What should the result set look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this also

```
with cte as
(
SELECT SUM(value1) as sum1, SUM(value2) as sum1 ,  MAX(value2) as maxValue2
FROM example_groups
GROUP BY user_name
)
select * from cte where maxvalue2 = (select max(maxValue2) from cte)
```

or

```
with cte as
(
SELECT SUM(value1) as sum1, SUM(value2) as sum1 ,  MAX(value2) as maxValue2
FROM example_groups
GROUP BY user_name
)
select max(maxValue2) as max_Of_all from cte
```

- [**The Best Postgres Feature You're Not Using**](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/11/18/best-postgres-feature-youre-not-using/)
- [**PostgreSQL - WITH Clause**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_with_clause.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I am not overly familiar with Postgres syntax, but based on the documentation it would appear that the RETURNING statement returns/computes value(s) on a per-row basis for each row that is inserted so using an aggregate function (MAX) on a per-row basis has no meaning in this context.

There are perhaps more elegant ways of writing the query but this should suffice (assuming I have made no syntax mistakes):

```
SELECT SUM(value1), SUM(value2), MAX(value2) AS max_all_groups
FROM example_groups
GROUP BY user_name
ORDER BY max_all_groups DESC -- order from highest to lowest maximum value per user
LIMIT 1 -- get top row
```

Obviously if you are just wanting the max value across all groups returned for your INSERT INTO statement and do not care about the SUM(...) columns you can remove them.

I hope that helps and no doubt more experienced Postgres users will be able to correct me on the above.